# Linq GroupBy behaves differently for classes and values

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

Please consider the following code segment:

```
var list = new string[] { "ab", "ab", "cd", "cd", "cd" };
var groups = list.GroupBy(l => l);
var count = groups.Count();
```

The results:

```
count: 2,
groups: [{ Key: "ab", elements: ["ab", "ab"] }, { Key: "cd", elements: ["cd", "cd", "cd"] }]
```

When I do the same for class X:

```
public class X
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

And the same algorithm is used in order to create the grouped results:

```
var list2 = new X[] 
    {
        new X { A = 1, B = "b1" },
        new X { A = 1, B = "b1" },
        new X { A = 2, B = "b2" },
        new X { A = 2, B = "b2" },
        new X { A = 2, B = "b2" },
    };

var groups2 = list2.GroupBy(l => l);
var count2 = groups2.Count();
```

I would expect the same behavior. I would say count2 is 2, and groups2 contains the two different distinct data sets with 2 and 3 elements respectively.

However when I run this, I get 5 as count and a list of groups containing one item each. Why is the different behavior? I would expect the same aggregation algorithm to behave the same.

Thanks in advance for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupBy` uses default equality comparer for the type unless you provide any implementation.The default comparer for reference types only return true if they are same instances, meaning they have same references. If this is not the behaviour you want you have two choices:

1. Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in your clas
2. Implement an [`IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for your type and pass it to [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534334(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: We override Equals to tell define the mean of equality between these class's objects. What about the override of GetHashCode?
thank you

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil well that is the point here.determining if two objects are equal so they can put into the same group.overriding gethashcode only is not enough you need to override them both. if gethashcode returns false the Equals method is called.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. It's kinda obvious afterwards :) The difference between Linq to Objects and Linq to Entities always fools me.